# IOS email works on IOS 6.1.4 (iphone 5) but not on IOS 6.1.3 (iphone 4)

Tags: iphone, ios, email

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailcontroller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
[mailcontroller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
```

This is what I used in my code to set up the email object.  It works fine on iphone 5 but it forces an exit on iphone 4.  Please help!

Comment: Does it crash? Is there any error? Anything from the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Try this apple doc for [complete accurate implementation of email](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendingaMailMessage.html)
also check your deployement target set while creating build

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```